# Container implementation using templates and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm trying to implement a generic ranked tree container by inheriting a basic 2-3 tree container

basic tree is declared as follows :

```
    template<typename T>
    class Node{
    // etc..
    }

    template<typename T>
    class Tree{
    Node* root;
    // etc
   }
```

and suppose i wanted to implement a tree of integers, i though i could declare a class as follows :

```
class RankedNode : public Node<int>{

// ...
}

class RankedTree : public Tree<int>{
RankedNode root*; // for example

// ...
}
```

The class RankedNode will include additional fields to the class Node, that aid in fast traversal of the tree ( O(log n) ) , and by using inheritance i'll be able to prevent code duplication.

However, i don't know how to go about doing so correctly, any ideas would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You could start by making `Tree` a template on `N`, (the *node type*), instead of `T` (the value type):

```
template<typename T>
class Node{
   // etc..
}

template<typename N>
class Tree{
   N* root;
   // etc
}
```

This way you could write

```
class RankedNode : public Node<int>{

// ...
}

class RankedTree : public Tree<RankedNode>{
    // RankedNode* root; <- remove this; it is already in Tree<RankedNode>

    // ...
}
```

and add only fields that are really new compared to base classes.